# Redirecting specific URLs to different directory

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect mywebsite.com/some-directory to a different directory other than the root of mywebsite.com. I used the following configuration :

```
server {
  server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
  listen 80;

  root /path/to/the/root/directory/of/mywebsite;
  index index.php index.html index.htm get.html ;

  ssl on;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate my_ssl.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key my_key.key;

  location /some-directory {
    root /path/to/directory;
  }
}
```

The configuration loads the html file but doesn't load the assets in the same directory.

I found a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/246609/trouble-with-nginx-and-serving-from-multiple-directories-under-the-same-domain) (or probably the exact one), but the issue was different. I was able to fix that on my own.

I also tried using the alias as suggested in the answer above; but in vain.

My `/path/to/directory/` has `some-directory` within it, and nginx serves the index.html file just fine. The problem occurs when the HTML file tries to access the files (or folders) within `/path/to/directory/some-directory`. They all return 404 Not Found.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the URL of these other resource files, and what is their physical location within your document root?

Comment: @RichardSmith, the physical files are all within `some-directory` itself. 
Say, the images are in `some-directory/assets/images`, css in `some-directory/assets/css/`, js in `some-directory/assets/js` and others in `some-directory/assets` as well.

Comment: And what URL is used to access these files? `http://mywebsite.com/some-directory/assets/css/filename.css` or something else?

Comment: Yes. The same. Those assets are 404.

Comment: Does `nginx-error.log` contain a detailed error message for the 404?

Comment: Nothing that we already don't know.
`[error] 6499#0: *xx open() "/path/to/some/directory/assets/images/image.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /some-directory/assets/images/image.png HTTP/1.1", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://mywebsite.com/some-directory/"`

Comment: I presume file permissions and ownership all look fine. No symlink or SELinux oddities? I am out of suggestions now.

Comment: I don't think so. I even tried 777 permissions (though I reverted them).

Comment: "Nginx locations are exclusive." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791415/nginx-alias-not-working# Please see my updated answer and try that.

Comment: Is this on topic on SF?

Answer (score 2):

I found a duplicate of this question but it is on StackOverflow not ServerFault.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628056/virtual-directory-counterpart-in-nginx

To redirect mywebsite.com/some-directory to a different directory than the root of your website you would have something like the code below.

```
root /path/to/the/root/directory/of/mywebsite;
index index.php index.html index.htm get.html;

location /some-directory/ {
    alias /path/to/some-directory/;
        index index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921479/nginx-alias-ignores-last-letter) thread about a similar problem.

Comment: I tried the alias alternative. That too serves the HTML file but not the assets.

Answer (score 0):

Searched the web extensively for a solution to this but couldn't find one. Came up with a solution that works.

Consider the case where your website's root is set to `/data/mywebsite`, so a request to `www.mywebsite.com/a/b.html` gets `/data/mywebsite/a/b.html` in response.
Say we want all requests starting with `www.mywebsite.com/blog` to go to a different directory, namely `/home/otherfolder`. So a request such as `www.mywebsite.com/blog/first.html` gets `/home/otherfolder/first.html` in response.

In the above case, you would create a soft `symlink` in the `/data/mywebsite` directory that points to `/home/otherfolder`. So to nginx it would appear as if all the files of `otherfolder` are present inside `/data/mywebsite/blog`.

```
cd /data/mywebsite
ln -s /home/otherfolder/ ./
mv ./otherfolder blog
```

Note that if you get a 404, you may need to give the `nginx` user access to the directories.